# In LaTeX how to have same font size in multiple tables?

Tags: tables, fontsize

I have two tables. One has more columns and the other one has very few. Now the problem is that the font size is not the same.

Here is table one includes lots of data:

```
%-------------------------------------------
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{ECF4FF} 
Treatment                         & Estimate. Mean in group Faunus   control & Estimate. Mean in group Faunus   with Tannin & p-value & statistic.t & conf.int1 & conf.int2 \\ \hline
p6\_gallic\_acid                  & 1.199                                    & 0.460                                        & 0.003   & 3.463       & 0.29      & 1.185     \\ \hline
p11\_di\_galloylglucose\_ester    & 1.037                                    & 0.419                                        & 0.006   & 3.127       & 0.204     & 1.032     \\ \hline
p22\_tri\_galloylglucose\_ester   & 0.370                                    & 0.187                                        & 0.026   & 2.369       & 0.024     & 0.342     \\ \hline
p28\_tetra\_galloylglucose\_ester & 0.665                                    & 0.220                                        & 0.003   & 3.387       & 0.170     & 0.720     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{T-test}
\label{Table:6.24}
\end{table}
%-------------------------------------------
```

the second table is comparatably small:

```
%-------------------------------------------
\begin{table}[H]
\tiny
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{ECF4FF} 
Material                          & p     \\ \hline
p6\_gallic\_acid                  & 0.003 \\ \hline
p11\_di\_galloylglucose\_ester    & 0.02  \\ \hline
p22\_tri\_galloylglucose\_ester   & 0.01  \\ \hline
p28\_tetra\_galloylglucose\_ester & 0.02  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Wilcoxon test}
\label{Table:6.25}
\end{table}
%-------------------------------------------
```

That is what they look like. It is clearly seen that they fit with the screen properly, However, they do not have the same font in size.

[image]

Can someone please help me to solve this issue?
I want a table where they will both fit with the screen and they both have same font size.

Comment: Don't use `\begin{adjustbox}`

Comment: scaling tables is always a bad idea as, as you demonstrate, it produces inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: but without adjustbox my table goes outside the page. how can i fix that? @david-carlisle

Comment: i tired without adjustbox but then my table goes outside the page  @phelype-oleinik

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134574

Comment: use `\small` or `\footnotesize ` also fix the headings so they are multi-line and not making the column widths so much wider than the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repeat after me: Do *not* use `\adjustbox` to shoe-horn a table into the width of the text block.

Instead, I suggest you (a) provide a bit more structure to the header row in the first table and (b) employ a `tabular*` environment to set the table's width to `\textwidth`. For the second table, I suggest you employ an ordinary `tabular` environment. Oh, giving the tables a more open "look", by omitting all vertical rules and employing fewer, but well-spaced horizontal rules, would be nice.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l cc *{4}{S[table-format=1.3]} }
\toprule
Treatment
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mean in group Faunus} 
& {$p$-val} & {$t$-stat} & {CI 1} & {CI 2} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-3}
& Control & with Tannin \\
\midrule
p6\_gallic\_acid                  & 1.199 & 0.460 & 0.003 & 3.463 & 0.29  & 1.185 \\ 
p11\_di\_galloylglucose\_ester    & 1.037 & 0.419 & 0.006 & 3.127 & 0.204 & 1.032 \\ 
p22\_tri\_galloylglucose\_ester   & 0.370 & 0.187 & 0.026 & 2.369 & 0.024 & 0.342 \\ 
p28\_tetra\_galloylglucose\_ester & 0.665 & 0.220 & 0.003 & 3.387 & 0.170 & 0.720 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Student-$t$ test}
\label{Table:6.24}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=1.3] @{}}
\toprule 
Material & {$p$-val} \\ 
\midrule
p6\_gallic\_acid                  & 0.003 \\ 
p11\_di\_galloylglucose\_ester    & 0.02  \\ 
p22\_tri\_galloylglucose\_ester   & 0.01  \\ 
p28\_tetra\_galloylglucose\_ester & 0.02  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Wilcoxon test}
\label{Table:6.25}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, i laughed out loud.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - :-)